# debian several ssh in shellscript file not works

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, debian, shell

In Ubuntu, I have a shell script file. In my script, the first ssh command to the Debian server works but the second ssh has error.
for example, if I have

```
 ssh -t "$userName"@"$ipAddress" "command1; command2; exit;"
 ssh -t "$userName"@"$ipAddress" "command3; command4; exit;"
```

the first ssh will work and the second ssh will have the error:

> "kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"

also if I have:

```
ssh ...
scp...
ssh ...
```

first ssh works but second ssh not works and has the error:

> "kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"

Also, I tested

```
 ssh -t "$userName"@"$ipAddress" "command1; command2; logout;"
```

instead of

```
 ssh -t "$userName"@"$ipAddress" "command1; command2; exit;"
```

but nothing changed and I have the same error.

Also, I tested

```
ssh -t "$userName"@"$ipAddress" "command1; command2; exit;"
wait
ssh -t "$userName"@"$ipAddress" "command3; command4; exit;"
```

but nothing changed and I have the same error.

Comment: Are you in charge of the Debian server? If not, can you ask the admin for help? What happens when you connect two `ssh` simultaneously (not one after another)? About how long do you need to wait after the first `ssh` terminates, until you can successfully `ssh` again? A workaround may be to create a [master connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33581/108618).

Comment: Thanks  Kamil Maciorowski.
I am the admin of this Debian server. the link you shared "master connection" looks exciting. I will look at that. Thanks again.